# Kernel of a transformation from $P^2 \to \mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to find a solution to this question:

Let T be a linear transformation such that $ T: P^2 \to ℝ^2$.

Specifically, for any $p ∈ P^2,  T $ maps $p$  to: 
      $$  \begin{pmatrix}
    p'(0) \\
    p'(0)
    \end{pmatrix}$$
where $p'$ is the derivative of $p$. Find the kernel of $T$.

I would really appreciate any help, I couldn't find out how to write the proper notation for a quadratic polynomial, but by $P^2$ I just mean any polynomial of the form $a + bx + cx^2$. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to help, but I don't understand the question. You tell us that $T$ is a linear transformation and then you express $T$ as a matrix.

Comment: What I meant is that T maps p to the matrix given, my mistake!

Answer (score 2):

$\ker T$ is the set of those $p(x)\in P_2[x]$ such that $p'(0)=0$. That means that$$\ker T=\left\{a+bx^2\,\middle|\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I may contribute. This is as far as i understood your question. Any $p$ will have the form $ax^{2} + bx + c$. So transformatiom $T$ of $p$ will result in $$ (b, b)$$ since $p'(0)= 2a(0) + b$. So the Kernel would be the set of quadratic polynomial with $b=0$, which is of the form $ax^{2} + c$.

- **Every element $v$ such that $T(v)=0$, is an element of the Kernel of $T$. And for all $v \in Ker(T)$, we will have $T(v)=0$**